# Asp.Net c# logging in to another website

Tags: c#, asp.net

I know this question has been asked quite a lot of times which is how I have got to where I am at with the code below however I just can't get it to work on the particular website I am trying to access. At the site I am trying to access I need to retrieve certain values from the page however things like price and availability only come up after logging in so I am trying to submit my login information and then go to the product page to get the information I need using HTML Agility Pack.

At the moment it seems to attempt the login however the website is either not accepting it or the cookies are not present on the next page load to actually keep me logged in.

If someone could help me with this I would be very grateful as I am not a programmer but have been assigned this task as part of a software installation.

```
protected void Button5_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    string LOGIN_URL = "http://www.videor.com/quicklogin/1/0/0/0/index.html";
    string SECRET_PAGE_URL = "http://www.videor.com/item/47/32/0/703/index.html?scriptMode=&CUSTOMERNO=xxx&USERNAME=xxx&activeTabId=0";

    // have a cookie container ready to receive the forms auth cookie
    CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();

    // first, request the login form to get the viewstate value
    HttpWebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(LOGIN_URL) as HttpWebRequest;
    webRequest.CookieContainer = cookies;
    StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(
          webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()
       );
    string responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
    responseReader.Close();

    string postData = "CUSTOMERNO=xxxx&USERNAME=xxxxx&PASSWORD=xxxxx";

    // now post to the login form
    webRequest = WebRequest.Create(LOGIN_URL) as HttpWebRequest;
    webRequest.Method = "POST";
    webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    webRequest.CookieContainer = cookies;

    // write the form values into the request message
    StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream());
    requestWriter.Write(postData);
    requestWriter.Close();

    // we don't need the contents of the response, just the cookie it issues
    webRequest.GetResponse().Close();

    // now we can send out cookie along with a request for the protected page
    webRequest = WebRequest.Create(SECRET_PAGE_URL) as HttpWebRequest;
    webRequest.CookieContainer = cookies;
    responseReader = new StreamReader(webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());

    // and read the response
    responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
    responseReader.Close();

    Response.Write(responseData);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a direct answer since I'm not sure what's wrong with your code (from a cursory glance it looks ok), but another approach is to use browser automation using [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) . The following code will actually load the page using Chrome (you can swap out Firefox or IE) and is simpler to code against. It also won't break if they add javascript or something.

```
        var driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(LOGON_URL);

        driver.FindElement(By.Id("UserName")).SendKeys("myuser");
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("Password")).SendKeys("mypassword");

        driver.FindElement(By.TagName("Form")).Submit();

        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(SECRET_PAGE_URL);

        // And now the html can be found as driver.PageSource. You can also look for
        // different elements and get their inner text and stuff as well.
```

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for the other way of doing it however unfortunately this needs to sit on a remote server so there won't be anyone logged on there to run it.

Comment: Selenium will successfully run on a remote server... we do it all the time where I work for automated testing. There are even entire business models around letting you run selenium tests on a cloud hosted server farm (for example, sounds like these guys do it: http://saucelabs.com/)

Comment: Ok thanks. I will have a bit more of a look into it as it may do the job a lot easier.

Comment: Just thought I would report back. This seems to do what we are looking for a lot easier so we are just going to stick it on it's own server to run and e-mail the results to the data analyst.

Comment: yay! glad I could be helpful! It's a little more overhead for a lot less work and more compatibility.